# Unable to mount device on Linux (XFS)

Tags: linux

I am unable to mount a device on my server due to error when mounting, the device is type XFS. 
The mount command returns message: "mount: structure needs cleaning"

I've tried using xfs_check and it just returns a message saying that there are entries in the log that need relaying and that you need to run xfs_repair -L where "-L" option deletes the log file but might/will result in data loss/corruption.

Does anyone know if you can access/mount the drive without repairing, or anyway to minimise data loss?

Comment: You'll probably have better luck asking this over at http://www.superuser.com

Comment: Or [Unix.SE](http://unix.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: thanks I will try superuser.com

Answer (score 1):

If the filesystem is corrupted *and* requires log replay, all you can do is run

```
# xfs_repair -L <DEVICE>
```

to zero out the log and repair the metadata in the filesystem.

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to repair the partition using GParted.

1. Open GParted
2. Select your device
3. Unmount the defective partition
4. Select Partition -> Check

[image: GParted]

5. Apply changes